# How to fix ANR error for updating widgets

Tags: android, widget, android-anr-dialog

I have a JobScheduler service triggering to update the widget UI.

```
@Override
    public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters params) {
        //Offloading work to a new thread.
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                // Here we receive updated data and store to SharedPreferences 
                ...
                MyWidgetProvider.updateWidgets(getApplicationContext());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onStartJob: " + e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                jobFinished(params, false);
            }
        }).start();
        return true;
    }
```

My AppWidgetProvider:

```
protected static void updateWidget(Context context) {
    try {
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
        int[] appWidgetIds = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext()).getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
        if (appWidgetIds != null) {
            if (appWidgetIds.length > 0) {
                for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
                    try {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);

                        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
                        intent.setAction(UPDATE_WIDGET);
                        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error" + e.getMessage());
    }
}


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    try {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (extras != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(action)) {
            int appWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
            if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
                if (action.equals(UPDATE_WIDGET)) {

                    RemoteViews remoteViews = getRemoteView(context);
                    // Here read from the SharedPreferences and updates the remoteViews
                    ....

                    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
                    appWidgetManager.partiallyUpdateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
                } 
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onReceive() error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I am getting ANR errors at Broadcast of Intent { act=.....UPDATE_WIDGET }

Since I cannot reproduce on my device, I have to guess what the solution would be.

**Solution #1**
Instead of saving to the SharedPreferences and read from the SharedPreferences, I can pass the value which will decrease the UI runtime. This I can make the change right away.

**Solution #2**
Instead of for looping per widget id and call broadcast per widget id, should I call one broadcast and pass all widget ids? Wouldn't it make onReceive() to take longer to execute? (since it has to update all widgets).

Solution #2 is what I am not sure about. Will this change be helpful? or causes ANR to happen more often?

Comment: Have you solved the issue? I have the same problem on some Samsung devices. I think this is the evil battery keeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Solution #1 
Either passing data value through intent to avoid loading data from SharedPreferences and/or loading SharedPreferences from the WorkerThread eliminated the ANR errors.

I have tried solution #2 and I am not sure if it helped eliminating ANR or not.

Comment: I know it's been almost 5 years, but were you lucky in eliminating the ANRs after solution 2? Can you *maybe* share a code snippet?

Comment: It was the solution #1 that actually solved the ANR (SharedPreferences).
In terms of ANR, Solution #2 not only made no difference, but also solution should a lot different nowadays with Jetpack Glance (https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/12/announcing-jetpack-glance-alpha-for-app.html)